# FireMonkey Android - handle callback message (JHandle) of JAR object

Tags: java, android, delphi, jar, firemonkey

I have a big problem for a long time - I am looking for a solution everywhere, but after really many hours of testing I can not find a sensible solution.

I have a JAR library for the Zebra printer and a PAS file for it (http://aboutit.pl/MobilePrinter.zip). I need a piece of code in Delphi that will handle a callback (JHandle) single procedure from a JAR library.

Something like this:

```
TPrintCallback = class (TJavaLocal, JHandler_Callback)
  function handleMessage (msg: JMessage): Boolean; cdecl;
end;

TfrmMain = class (TForm)
  [..]
private
  FCallback: TPrintCallback;
  FHandler: JHandler;
end;

[...]

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate (Sender: TObject);
begin
  FCallback: = TPrintCallback.Create;
  FHandler: = TJHandler.JavaClass.init (FCallback);
  FPrinter1: = TJMobilePrinter.JavaClass.Init (TAndroidHelper.Context,FHandler, TJLooper.JavaClass.getMainLooper);
  [...]
end;

function TPrintCallback.handleMessage (msg: JMessage): Boolean;
begin
  Result: = True;
  ShowMessage (msg.what.ToString + '' + msg.arg1.ToString);
end;
```

I would like the handleMessage function to receive messages, e.g. about the printer's connection. Of course, the printer object can do it, but messages do not reach the Delphi application.

I also tried the RegisterNatives method, but also without success

```
procedure RegisterN;
var
  PEnv: PJNIEnv;
  ReceiverClass: JNIClass;
  NativeMethod: JNINativeMethod;
begin
  try
    PEnv := TJNIResolver.GetJNIEnv;
    ReceiverClass := TJNIResolver.GetJavaClassID('com/zebra/printer/service/PrinterHandler');
    NativeMethod.Name := 'handleMessage';
    NativeMethod.Signature := '(Landroid/os/Message;)V';
    NativeMethod.FnPtr := @handleMessage;

    PEnv^.RegisterNatives(PEnv, ReceiverClass, @NativeMethod, 1);
    PEnv^.DeleteLocalRef(PEnv, ReceiverClass);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

I am ready to pay for any hint, where to look for a solution to this problem - I am in desperation. ;-)

Edit:

In Java it's look like this:

```
mMobilePrinter = new MobilePrinter(this, mHandler, null);



private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MobilePrinter.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                case MobilePrinter.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    setStatus(getString(R.string.title_connected_to, mConnectedDeviceName));
                    mListView.setEnabled(true);
                    mIsConnected = true;
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    break;

                case MobilePrinter.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    setStatus(R.string.title_connecting);
                    break;


            case MobilePrinter.MESSAGE_PRINT_COMPLETE:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Complete to print", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;


            }
        }
    };
```

I need to have procedure handleMessage(Message msg) in Delphi...

Comment: You're not showing enough code, or you're missing some pretty vital code, namely: where/if you're using connect to actually connect to a printer. Also, using ToString won't convert "what" and "arg1" to Delphi strings; you need to use JStringToString for that.

Comment: Of course, you're right with JStringToString, but this are not problems. The printer works after connection and prints correctly. However, to avoid a few problems I want to support the message about establishing a connection (now I just wait a few seconds and I hope that the connection will succeed). I will handle correct handleMessage - I knwo how to do it. But the problem is that this function is not run at all - no messages are reaching for it.

Comment: If I actually had a Zebra printer, I'd see if I could troubleshoot the issue, as it seems your code is correct, and you say you're connecting successfully.

Comment: What happens if you pass `nil` for the looper parameter? What version of Delphi is this? Is it one where you can sensibly call `ShowMessage` from the thread a Java method will run in? Might a toast message be a better indicator?

Comment: 1) nil as looper nothing change - messages are not passing
2) Delphi 10.2.2 (Tokyo)
3) Ofcourse You have right about showmessge, but this is not a problem. This Was only a example - this functions is never executing

Comment: can you show the java code equivalent code of what you are trying to do? because your question is unclear .. can you try also in java if it's work ?

Comment: Of course - I had added Java code to my question.

I havent try to work with Java, but this are official examples from Zebra - they should work. I have searched in internet for examples of using JHandle, but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

First, should know the Handler class of JAVA, so that you could port the Handler class to Delhpi!!!
I think in dehphi, you not init an Looper which delay the messge of Handler! in java, the main thread already did this.